# Централизованная обработка ошибок

Tags: java, исключения

Мне нужно обрабатывать все ошибки в одном классе (на самом деле - не все, но это не важно).

---

Обработка должна происходить так, чтобы обработчик сам перенаправлял ошибку в нужный класс:

```
try {
    //Ошибка
} catch (Exception e) {
    handleError(e); //Передается в нужный класс (обработчик)
}
```

Варианта решения я нашел два:

1. Вызывать статические метод класса `ErrorHandler.handle(e)`.
2. Импортировать тот же статический метод класса статическим импортом и вызывать сразу `handle(e)`.

Только в обоих случаях идет прямая привязка к классу, что нежелательно.

---

Есть ли какой-то способ централизованно обрабатывать ошибки, чтобы их получал один класс? Хотел рассмотреть вариант с логгером, но не нашел такой логгер, чтобы он получал ошибки в определенный класс.

Comment: Можно весь код из main обернуть в try/catch, а все остальные классы и методы дополнить throws. Но в целом - это порнография какая то

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть способ для перехвата всех необработанных ошибок в потоке.
В начале делаем класс реализующий UncaughtExceptionHandler

```
public class TryMe implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        Log.d("TryMe", "Something wrong happened!");
    }
}
```

Где прописываем алгоритм обработки.

А далее в нужном потоке пишем следующее.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new TryMe());
```

И все, что не обрабатывается `try/catch` попадет в этот класс.
PS А раз это интерфейс с одним методом, можно упаковать все в лямбду.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, throwable) -> {Log.d("TryMe", "Something wrong happened!");});
```